# How to change i3 theme

Tags: arch-linux, i3

So I'm trying to change the theme of i3 to this:
http://lovelybacon.deviantart.com/art/i3-Finally-it-all-comes-together-563203883
and I have no clue how to do this, does anyone have a tutorial or can tell me how to do it as I quite cannot find how to do it. (I'm using arch if it matters)

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding there's no "change theme and apply" utility for i3. There's lxappearance, but that just changes your GTK theme, which isn't really the deal here.

It's all about editing your i3config and i3status configuration file. i3config should be located under /etc/i3/ but I would recommend you to copy it to your /home folder.

Answer (score 1):

I found lovelybacon i3 conf on the interweb ..  http://dotshare.it/dots/1022/ and http://dotshare.it/dots/1030/  I have not tried it.. But it looks like only i3 conf settings to me.. Also an other background image. I use feh to set my background image.

I don't like to link conf files links in a response. Should I copy paste the conf here?